# How to do a ls -d in powershell

Tags: powershell, ls, equivalent

I need to list existing directories without listing files into them :

```
PS C:\Users\myHomeDIR> cat .\toto.txt
.\.config
C:\DA FI
PS C:\Users\myHomeDIR> cat .\toto.txt | dir | % FullName
C:\Users\myHomeDIR\.config\scoop
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\DA FI' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:18
+ cat .\toto.txt | dir | % FullName
+                  ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\DA FI:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\Users\myHomeDIR>
```

I expect this output instead (like LINUX `ls -d` would) :

```
C:\Users\myHomeDIR\.config
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\DA FI' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:18
+ cat .\toto.txt | dir | % FullName
+                  ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\DA FI:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) rather than [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (one of whose built-in aliases is `dir`), as the former always reports the input items *themselves*, even if they're directories:

Using its built-in `gi` alias, and `gc` rather than `cat` as a `Get-Content` alias:

```
gc .\toto.txt | gi | % FullName
```

---

As for the **general question**:

- **`Get-Item` is the equivalent of Unix `ls -d`**

  - Like `ls -d`, `Get-Item` reports whatever paths it is given as *themselves*, i.e. it doesn't list the *content* of *directories* among the input paths (the latter is what `ls` does by default).
  - However, instead of reporting *strings* (names/paths only by default), `Get-Item` reports *rich objects* ([`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and/or [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances) that allow flexible later processing (e.g., as shown in the question,
    `% FullName` extracts the full paths via the `.FullName` property, and `.Name` would yield just the name).
- By contrast, **`Get-ChildItem -Directory`**, while seemingly a closer analog, **works *differently***:

  - With *literal* input paths:

    - If a *directory* path is provided (by default: the *current* directory), it enumerates that directory's *child directories* - only, *as themselves*, i.e. without listing *their content*.

      - In other words: it enumerates the *children* of the target directory, but only if they are *directories themselves*.
    - With *file* paths as *input*, it acts the same as without `-Directory` (and, in this case, therefore like `ls -d`)
  - With [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcard) as input:

    - Only *directories* among the matching items are reported.
    - If you *omit* `-Directory`, files are reported too - and matching directories are still reported *as themselves*.

      - In other words: With a *wildcard*-based input path pattern - only - `Get-ChildItem` *by default* acts like `ls -d`; e.g., `Get-ChildItem *` basically acts the same as `ls -d *` (except that the former emits *rich objects*, whereas the latter emits *strings* (names only)).